# Menu with submenu on QPushButton: Missing arrow and weird selection behaviour

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I'm using a QMenu with submenus on a QPushButton as a sort of hierarchical combo box for the user to select something from a large list of things.

For some reason the submenu indicator (right arrow) doesn't show up. It does show up on regular menus in my menubar, just not when installed on a button. Also, selection from a large list by typing first letters doesn't seem to work. The selection seems to jump to seemingly random entries when I start typing. It seems to work with smaller lists of only a few entries.

How do I fix this?

[image: Missing Arrow Example]

Here's a minimal code example to reproduce the issues:

```
import sys
import pytz
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMenu, \
    QVBoxLayout

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QWidget()
w.show()

btn = QPushButton('Button')
w.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
w.layout().addWidget(btn)

menu = QMenu()
submenu = menu.addMenu('Time Zones')
for zone in pytz.all_timezones_set:
    action = submenu.addAction(zone.split('/')[-1])
btn.setMenu(menu)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My platform: Mac OS X 10.12.6, Qt 5.10, Python 3.6.4

Comment: For me it does show up, macOS 10.13.4, PyQT5 5.10.1 from Homebrew. On which platform do you see this not working?

Comment: The menu arrows work fine for me on arch linux (qt 5.11.0, pyqt 5.10.1). I think the typing-first-letters behaviour must be platform-specific, because it does not work in menus in ***any*** application on my system. For example, in qt designer, if I show the "view" menu and type "w" or "p", nothing happens. The behaviour does work as expected in list-widgets, though. So perhaps you should use a [tree-view in a combo-box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27172160/984421) instead of menus.

Comment: I added the platform specs to my question.

Comment: Also, [according to apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204434) typing a menu item's name should select it.